# Create intervals with equal spacing around 0

Tags: r

I am making breaks based on input values in R, and then applying equal intervals based on those values.

To do this I supply an input vector:

```
for_break = c(-100, -90, -80, -50, 0, 3, 5, 20, 30, 40, 80)
```

then I apply equal interval breaks, with 5 intervals total using:

```
library(classInt)

breaks = classIntervals(for_break, n = 5, style = "equal", intervalClosure = "right")
```

I return the breaks with:

```
breaks_num = breaks$brks
```

which returns:

```
[1] -100  -64  -28    8   44   80
```

I want to have a break centered around the number 0 though.

Is there a way to supply an input vector and provide equal interval spacing around zero on both the positive and negative side?

As an example if I supplied this input vector:

```
c(-8, -6, -3, -2, 2, 4, 6, 9)
```

and specified that I wanted equal spacing on the positive and negative side of zero, with 3 intervals on each side I would get:

```
c(-8.000, -5.333, -2.666, 0.000, 3.000, 6.000, 9.000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
for_break = c(-100, -90, -80, -50, 0, 3, 5, 20, 30, 40, 80)

equalSpacing <- function( vector, per.side ) {
  negs <- seq.int( from = min( vector ), to = 0, length.out = per.side + 1L )
  pos <- seq.int( from = 0, to = max( vector ), length.out = per.side + 1L )
  return( c( negs, pos[ pos != 0 ] ) )
}

equalSpacing( for_break, 4 )
```

Comment: Thank you, I really like this example.  I returned this error on my real dataset `Error in seq.int(from = min(vector), to = 0, length.out = per.side + 1L) : 
  'from' must be finite`.  Obviously your example works but any ideas why this might occur?

Comment: What's your input vector?

Comment: It is very long, I am thinking it has to do with the object type.  Forgive me I am new to R from python.  When I do `typeof(object)` I get `double`, so all I can tell is it is a float

Comment: what does `min(object)` return?

Comment: It returns `-0.501841`.  I had `NA` in my data, I removed them and it works now.  Thanks again.

Comment: That seems odd, `seq.int` should run fine with that. I'm happy to try with your vector if you'd like to share it.

Comment: Yea, that actually wasn't it, something funky as going on and it executed but with different input.  How can I share the vector with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136519/discussion-between-rosscova-and-stefano-potter).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this logic and create a function out of it.

```
x=c(-8, -6, -3, -2, 2, 4, 6, 9)
i=max(x)/3
j=min(x)/3
c(rev(seq(0, min(x), j)), seq(0, max(x), i)[-1])
```

Comment: :) you beat me to it.

Comment: It was probably by seconds.

Comment: Indeed. I'll leave mine here as well anyway, since it's just slightly different.